# How to set build type(Release/Debug) for Continuous deployment using GIT in Azure App Service

Tags: git, azure-web-app-service

I'm using the Azure Continuous deployment service. It is useful, but I don't know how to change the build type to Debug. It always works as Release build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by adding the following App Setting in the Azure Portal:

Set `SCM_BUILD_ARGS` to `-p:Configuration=Debug`.

Make sure to use a `-` an not `/` for the switch, as slash has some issues in some situations.

See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#adding-flags-to-the-msbuild-command-line) for more info. Another option is to use a full custom deployment script, but that's overkill if you just want to change that.